# Cypress auth0 redirect to login on successful auth

Tags: javascript, cypress, auth0

Trying to make the auth0 authenticate login with cypress, followed this instructions (https://auth0.com/blog/end-to-end-testing-with-cypress-and-auth0/)
I got a successful 200 response on POST but keep getting redirected to the login page whenever I do a cy.visit()

Tried encapsulating the code on cy.session

```
Cypress.Commands.add('logint', (overrides = {}) => {
    Cypress.log({
      name: 'loginViaAuth0',
    });
  
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: Cypress.env('auth_url'),
      body: {
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: Cypress.env('auth_username'),
        password: Cypress.env('auth_password'),
        audience: Cypress.env('auth_audience'),
        scope: 'openid profile email',
        client_id: Cypress.env('auth_client_id'),
        client_secret: Cypress.env('auth_client_secret'),
      },
    };
    cy.request(options);
  });
```

```
import logint from '../support/commands'

describe('login', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.session("User session",()=>{
        cy.logint()
        .then((resp) => {
          return resp.body;
        })
        .then((body) => {
          const {access_token, expires_in, id_token} = body;
          const auth0State = {
            nonce: '',
            state: 'some-random-state'
          };
          const callbackUrl = `/callback#access_token=${access_token}&scope=openid&id_token=${id_token}&expires_in=${expires_in}&token_type=Bearer&state=${auth0State.state}`;
          cy.visit(callbackUrl, {
            onBeforeLoad(win) {
              win.document.cookie = 'com.auth0.auth.some-random-state=' + JSON.stringify(auth0State);
            }
          });
        })
        
    })

});

    it('should successfully log into our app', () => {
       
     
    cy.visit('/app/projects/personal')
   

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about auth0 and never tried it but from my research i found.

- This page for possible solution: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71608719/17844126)
- This article that could help solve your problem: [community.auth0.com](https://community.auth0.com/t/error-when-testing-with-cypress/94124)
- And as the post suggests follow the official page of cypress: [docs.cypress.io](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/auth0-authentication#Auth0-Application-Setup)
- Very detailed blog about working with auth0 [sandrino.dev](https://sandrino.dev/blog/writing-cypress-e2e-tests-with-auth0)